# Unable to write net cdf precipitation file in csv file

Tags: python

I am not being able to write this net cdf precipitation file in csv file. how I have to do it ? please help me

```py
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
import csv
import pandas as pd

nc= Dataset('D:/1 BVEERI/Desertation EX/pune_precp/CCS_2019-09-10114905am.nc', 'r')
print(nc)

print(nc.variables.keys()) #get all variables
precp=nc.variables['precip']
print(precp)

for d in nc.dimensions.items():
     print(d)
precp.dimensions
precp.shape

time=nc.variables['datetime']
time=time[:]
print(time)

x=nc.variables['lon']
lon=x[:]
print(lon)

y=nc.variables['lat']
lat=y[:]
print(lat)


precip=nc.variables['precip']
precip=precip[:]
print(precip)
```

I want it in the following format:

```
precipation  ----  latitude -----  longitude -----  time
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use pandas `to_csv` function:

```
#create a dataframe
df=pd.DataFrame({'Precipitation' : precip,
                 'Latitude' : lat,
                 'Longitude' : lon,
                 'Time' : time})
df.to_csv('precipitation.csv')
```